# Calculating the ripeness rate in fruits

Tags: fruit

I need a way to calculate avocado ripeness rate in my experiment so I need a quantitative way, I'm not sure if calculating the cellular respiration for the avocado will result in ripeness rate for the fruit, if that's true I need references if you got.
And if you got another better quantitative ways to get the "rate" of the fruit ripeness.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, [ethylene](https://web.archive.org/web/20100526120225/http://www.mindfully.org/Plastic/Ethylene-Gas.htm) production is used to gauge fruit ripeness.  [This paper](http://209.143.153.251/Journals/ASHS/ASHS_1978_103_PG_576-578.pdf) (PDF download) outlines an experiment measuring ethylene production from Hass avocados at different temperatures over several days.  It appears they used gas chromatography to measure both ethylene and CO<sub>2</sub> concentrations.

[image]